# If $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $(M, d)$, show that $d(x_n, y) \rightarrow d(x, y)$ for $y\in M$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Wanted to check if my solution was right (because I wasn't too sure).

Since we have $x_n \rightarrow x$, that means we have:
$\forall\epsilon> 0, \exists N>0$ so whenever $n \geq N$ we have $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$.

So by the triangle inequality we get: $d(x_n, x) \leq d(x_n, y) + d(y, x) =d(x_n, y) + d(x, y) <\epsilon$.

$\therefore$ From the inequality: we get $d(x_n, x) - d(x, y) < \epsilon$ which is what we wanted to show.

Now I'm supposed to show, if $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$, then $d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow d(x, y)$.

How would I do that?

Comment: The solution is not correct. The way you use the triangle inequality does not justify the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y_n)$$

And also

$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_n) + d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,y)$$

From these two statements you should be able to derive:

$$|d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y)| \leq d(x,x_n) + d(y,y_n)$$